# Simulating a Key in Input Field VANILLA Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, key, simulate

I feel like I'm stupid. My English is not very good so I can't understand anything when I read solutions. I prepared a lab for you guys. Please look at it.

(Please find solution as Vanilla Javascript instead of JQuery)

HTML:

```
    <div id = "row1">
      <span>Word</span>
      <span>Word2</span>
      <span>Word3</span>
    </div>

    <input id="inputfield">
```

JS:

```
    var childs = document.getElementById('row1').childNodes;
    var input = document.getElementById('inputfield');
    childs.forEach(e => {
        if(e.innerText){
            console.log(e.innerText);
            input.value += e.innerText;
            //simulate a key press right here (space)
            //input's value have to be like this > Word Word2 Word3
        }
    })
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when a keypress happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to have an array of values and use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method of the array to create a string out of it. With `join()` you can add a string between each word, like a space, or a letter if you want.

The snippet below loops over each `<span>` element with the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods to turn the elements in an array and to return a new array with only the `textContent` value of each `<span>`. Now you have an array that looks like this.

```
['Word', 'Word2', 'Word3']
```

And by using `join(' ')` on that array you can turn it into a string what spaces between each word.

```
var words = ['Word', 'Word2', 'Word3'];
words.join(' '); // "Word Word2 Word3"
```

```js
var childs = document.querySelectorAll('#row1 span');
var input = document.getElementById('inputfield');

var words = Array.from(childs).map(child => child.textContent);
input.value = words.join(' ');
```

```html
<div id = "row1">
  <span>Word</span>
  <span>Word2</span>
  <span>Word3</span>
</div>

<input id="inputfield">
```

### Edit

You can create your own keyboard events with the [`KeyboardEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) constructor. With this you can create your own event with the key that is supposed to be pressed. But you'll have to listen for the event as well as the browser won't know what to do with it without you telling it what to do.

With [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) you can fire the event from a certain element. And when you listen to that event on that element, you will catch the created event.

On your input listen for the `keydown` event and check if the pressed key is the spacebar. In the example below either the `key`, `keyCode` and `code` represent the spacebar, but in different ways.

```js
var childs = document.querySelectorAll('#row1 span');
var input = document.getElementById('inputfield');

input.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.key === "Space" || event.keyCode === 32 || event.code === '32') {
    console.log('Spacebar simulated');
    input.value += ' ';
  }
});

childs.forEach(e => {
  if (e.innerText) {
    input.value += e.innerText;
    var keydownEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      key: "Space",
      keyCode: 32,
      code: '32'
    });
    input.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <span>Word</span>
  <span>Word2</span>
  <span>Word3</span>
</div>

<input id="inputfield">
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for your answer but this is not what im looking for. I want 'simulate a key in inputfield'. I have to simulate a key (like i pressed it). I have to do this in that way. So this answer is correct but not what i wanted. Can you do this thing in my way too? (By the way thank you so much again really and sorry for my weird English :D)

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a second example in which the spacebar is "simulated". There is also an event listener which listens for the `keydown` event to add your space inside the input element after each word. It would help a lot if you could explain the **why** to your question, because your question is not how you would normally do such a thing. Your *weird english* is no problem as long as we understand each other. ;)

Comment: This solution is very good and what im looking for but i have a question. We simulated a space key but its not adding space in our input except we add input.value += ' '; But i want to add space in input when space key is simulated.

Comment: That is simply not possible. Your keyboard input is picked up by the OS which then tells the browser what to do with that input. You only have control over what the user can do on your site within the browser, but not what the OS should tell the browser what to do. Basically the browser does the same thing as the event handler when pressing the spacebar. And again, **why** do you need it to be a "simulated" keypress?

Comment: I just test something about in a fast typing site. Just trying to earn some bug bounty from that. Is there a problem for this thing? I just scared the way you talked :D

Answer (score 0):

if you want something to happen on keypress you can add `onkeypress="function()"` to your input box, but most likely you want `onkeyup="function()"` or you wont be able to see the results of the key pressed in the input

```
    <div id = "row1">
      <span>Word</span>
      <span>Word2</span>
      <span>Word3</span>
    </div>

    <input id="inputfield" onkeyup="run(this)">
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are wanting to happen when the keypress happens, but you will write your JS like this

```
  const childs = document.getElementById('row1').childNodes;
  const input = document.getElementById('inputfield');
  childs.forEach(e => {
    if(e.innerText){
      console.log(e.innerText);
      input.value += e.innerText + ' ';
      // simulate a key press right here (space)
      // input's value have to be like this > Word Word2 Word3
    }
  });
```

checkout the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kcbst5oe/1/

Comment: I want 'simulate a key in inputfield'. I have to simulate a key (like i pressed it). I have to do this in that way. I have no business with onkeyup event so. Read the comments that i wrote in code. 

      //input.value += e.innerText;
      //simulate a key press right here (like i pressed space key)
      //input's value have to be like this > Word Word2 Word3

Comment: "simulate a key" is not a thing. You need to find another way to explain what you are wanting to achieve

Comment: Do you just want the input field to have a space between each word? If thats all you want just update `input.value += e.innerText + ' ';`

Comment: example updated with new jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kcbst5oe/1/

Comment: var keydownEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      key: "Space",
      keyCode: 32,
      code: '32'
    });
    input.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);

I want something like that. 

input.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent) -> this thing is have to add space in my input everytime i call it. Emiel is answered my question but this dispatchEvent method is not adding space in my input.

Look at it -> https://jsfiddle.net/tb58y1aj/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pLqehxs4/

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need a simulated key press?